# PHP Query only works with certain e-mail-address

Tags: php, android

So, I'm creating an android app, that needs to be able to communicate with a database, that is online. I can connect to the DB with no problems and the query works, as far as I know. However, when testing this, through the browser, it only returns with some e-mail-addresses? Can anyone explain why this isn't working?

```
    <?php
    function resultToArray($result) {
        $rows = array();
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $rows[] = $row;
        }
        return $rows;
    }
    $mysqli = new mysqli("serverhost", "username", "password", "db_to_use");
    $email = $_GET['email'];
    $query = ("SELECT * FROM Cards WHERE Email_FK='{$email}'");
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
    $rows = resultToArray($result);

    echo json_encode($rows);
    $result->free();
    ?>
```

When I run this, with one email address; mooh_****@hotmail.com, it works fine and echoes a json array;
[image]

However, if I run it with another email address; kasper.****@gmail.com, it returns nothing. (I'm not gonna post an image of that, as I just get a blank screen!)

And it's happening with other email addresses as well. Some work, some don't.

And just to show, that there is actually something in the DB associated to the kasper.****@gmail.com address;

[image]

Can someone please tell me, what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure their is no whitespace before and after email address in db and while quering. You can use trim function to remove it.

Comment: why hv you inserted `{}`?

Comment: Already done. I trim in android before sending the request to the php file.

Comment: Try `$email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['email'])` .

Comment: @N5. - Around email? Not sure. Some places say to do it, others omit them. It's been working for me until now.

Comment: Have you tried to log the android requests to a file? if so, what does it show? if not, do it!

Comment: @ojovirtual - Just tried that. Made no difference. One email returns a json array, the other returns nothing.

Comment: @PedroLobito - Even if I log Android requests, that wouldn't help. I am testing the php file in a browser and it's here it doesn't work.

Comment: no, log the received php requests.

Comment: can you just var_dump($rows) and tell me the result you get

Comment: @PedroLobito - I'm afraid I don't know what you mean. With the chance of my making myself look like a fool, but am I not only sending requests to php from android? Not receiving them? And if you mean the response from the when I run the php file through android, then I've done that, and it's empty for some email addresses but not for others.

Comment: From what I can understand, you're sending requests from android to php hosted on a server, so, log the requests on the server.

Comment: @AvinashBabu - When I use var_dump($rows) I get;
array(array(4) { [0]=> array(7) { ["Email_FK"]=> string(26) "kasper.****@gmail.com" ["BarcodeNumbers"]=> string(8) "57045399" ["MemberNumber"]=> NULL ["StoreID"]=> string(2) "30" ["HasBarcode"]=> string(1) "T" ["CardID"]=> string(3) "103" ["StoreName"]=> string(6) "Marcus" } [1]=> array(7) { ["Email_FK"]=> string(26) "kasper.****@gmail.com" ["BarcodeNumbers"]=> string(13) "1234124312312" ["MemberNumber"]=> NULL ["StoreID"]=> string(2) "17"... and so on... But not as json?

Comment: @qiTsuk: Can you output your json error please? `echo json_last_error()` I assume, that something can't be converted to json. You should, btw. check the rteurn value of json_encode, because it can be a string (the json string) or false in case of falure. If it returns false, return a default json string with some helpful error information for your app :)

Comment: @qiTsuk var_dump(json_last_error()) after json_encode

Comment: When I just did echo'ed json_last_error() it gave me 5, then I tried var_dump(last_json_error()) and it printed int(5)... So I found a switch case that tests and apparently I have a "Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded" error.

Comment: But, what is it that is wrongly encoded? Help? I'm kinda lost here! I've never worked with PHP before this project.

Comment: Can you set utf8 as your database connection encoding? See http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.set-charset.php (something like `$mysqli->set_charset( 'utf8' );`) and test again?

Comment: @Florian - Added the one line, now it works! Thank you man! That was a completely app breaking bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summary from comments:
It seems you have an error in your json_encode input, some suggestions:

(For a better error handling) You should check the return value of json_encode before outputting anything, e.g. do the following check:

```
<?php
$json = json_encode( $rows );
if ( $json ) {
  echo $json;
} else {
  echo '
  {
    "success": false,
    "reason": "json_error: ' . json_last_error() . '"
  }
  ';
}
```

With your JSON error 5 (which means something like false utf8 encoded string), try to find out where the problem is:

1. MySQL encoding problem: set the charset, e.g. with `$mysqli->set_charset( 'utf8' );`
2. Go through the data returned from mysql and check, if utf8 supports all used chars